# is there a nice output of Keras model.summary( )?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

is it possible to have a nice output of keras model.summary(), that can be included in paper, or can be ploted in a nice table like this.

[image]

Comment: How to get the output in dict format: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68128858/10375049

Answer (score 3):

You need to install graphvis and pydot, but you might like the results from this. It doesn't make a table but the graph is much better in my opinion.

```py
    from keras.utils import plot_model
    plot_model(model, to_file='model.png', show_shapes=True,show_layer_names=True)
```

But you would have to make properly named sub models if you want to nest the several layers together.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried this method before however for deep networks let's say Resnet50 it will give you a very long image ( because of the depth) that's why I'm thinking of something more tabular , so I can compact the representation and yet refer to the layer I want to specify in my paper (for instance layer conv2_branch1 )

Comment: you can combine several layers into a sub model and that would shorten the image, but I agree, it's not ideal